# Use AJAX to switch page, the page is using a lot of PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So for my next site, I want to use AJAX and PHP since it doesn't need to reload the page. It didn't work as expected, and after some internet searching, I turned to StackOverflow.

I have the following JS function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#page-wrap #cssmenu a').click(function() {
        var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        document.location.hash = $linkClicked;
        var $pageRoot = $linkClicked.replace('#page', '');
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $("#page-wrap #cssmenu a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "load.php",
                data: 'page='+$pageRoot,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(msg){
                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {
                    $('#main-content').slideUp().slideDown().html(msg);
                    $('#main-content section');
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

var hash = window.location.hash;
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
switch (hash) {
    case 'page2' :
      $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
      break;
    case 'page3' :
      $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
      break;
    case 'page4' :
      $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
      break;
}
});
```

The function loads this PHP file:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page'.$page.'.php'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page'.$page.'.php');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

In this case, I wanna load the staff page. Since it gets all of the staff from a DB it makes use of a lot of PHP, the following lines are from the file:

```
$rank = '10';
$query = $db->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM ht_users WHERE rank = ? OR rank2 = ?');
$query->bind_param('ss', $rank, $rank);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$count = $result->num_rows;
$base = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $direction = 'direction=3&';
    if($base == 1) $direction = '';
    if($base == $count) $direction = 'direction=4&';
    $content = '<div class="med">
        <b class="eigenaar"><center>' . $row['naam'] . '</center></b>
        <img src="imager?hb=img&user=' . $row['naam'] . '&' . $direction . 'head_direction=3&action=sit,wav&gesture=sml&size=l" />
        <div style="margin-right:275px;"></div>
        </div>
    ';
    echo $content;
    $base ++;
}
```

But when I run the page, it doesn't parse the code, but it just echo's it.

My question is how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Is that code wrapped in PHP tags? `<?php ... ?>`? By echo do you mean that the following code is appearing in plain text?

Comment: it doesnt parse the php code? if so did it parse it before so you can replicate? probably you used with shirtcodes disabled or your php is not configured correctly

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes, ofcourse its wrapped in tags :p. And it is appearing in plain text.

Comment: @Serg Normally it does. This problem started when I started using this AJAX code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is instead of `file_get_contents()` is look at [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) this should take care of your issue

```
if(file_exists('pages/page'.$page.'.php'))
{
    include 'pages/page' . $page . '.php';
} else {
    echo 'There is no such page!';  
}
```

if you wanted to parse the contents into a variable then you could look at [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

```
ob_start( );

include 'pages/page' . $page . '.php';

$html = ob_get_clean( );
```